# custom cell for UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c

I need to create an app which has a list of items, each item has an image a title, a subtitle a price and a description and I need 2 items per line (so I can't use a UITableView)
Is it possible to use a UICollectionView with custom cell in order to have the result I want or should I search another solution?

The custom cell layout should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You totally can !
Just create your custom UICollectionViewCell, then go in the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method in order to use it.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

1, create a xib file in the subclass of UIcollectionViewCell

2, register your xib in controller's viewdidload fun

```
  [mCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

3,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
 CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely customise your UICollectionView's Cell. But you will have to do following steps as well:

1. Register your Custom Cell to your collection view :

   ```
   [self.collectionView registerClass:[YourCustomClass class]
       forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
   ```
2. Secondly, inside your method : `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, you will have to call custom cell like this (as you do in tableView's custom cell  too):

   ```
   YourCustomClass *cell = (YourCustomClass *)[collectionView 
    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   ```

Here is a [tutorial](http://sledgedev.com/build-a-custom-uicollectionviewcell/) to make custom UICollectionView Cell